# Does ES5 have a counterpart to __lookupGetter__?

Tags: javascript, getter, ecmascript-5

I know `Object.defineProperty` is lots of fun and a great replacement for `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` nonstandard APIs, but is there a similar counterpart for `__lookupGetter__`? Or some way of achieving a similar thing?

Comment: Why do you need to lookup a getter function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure of the `__lookupGetter__` semantics but ES5 provides a new API `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` that gives you a descriptor object containing the attributes of a property and either its `value` or its `get` and/or `set` functions.

eg.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor("foo", {get foo() { return 5} }).get
```

Will give you the getter function

Comment: Worth noting there is no `Object.getPropertyDescriptor` so if you need something from the prototype chain you have to recursively climb it yourself.

Comment: @Domenic it's also worth nothing `Object.getPropertyDescriptor` is being added in ES6

Comment: [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) provides `Object.getPropertyDescriptor`.